# Making perl read from index.html file

Tags: perl, web-services, sh

I'm trying to use perl as my web server for a specific address:port number, 10.x.x.x:portNumber, while also having it show what's in my index.html file by default. However, perl does not show the contents of index.html when I run 10.x.x.x:portNumber in my browser. How can I get perl to read from a file?

This is the code I'm working with for this problem.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
{
package MyWebServer;
use HTTP::Server::Simple::CGI;
use base qw(HTTP::Server::Simple::CGI);
my %dispatch = (
    '/' => \&resp_hello,
);


sub handle_request {
    my $self = shift;
    my $cgi  = shift;
    my $path = $cgi->path_info();
    my $handler = $dispatch{$path};
    if (ref($handler) eq "CODE") {
        print "HTTP/1.0 200 OK\r\n";
        $handler->($cgi);
    } else {
        print "HTTP/1.0 404 Not found\r\n";
        print $cgi->header,
        $cgi->start_html('Not found'),
        $cgi->h1('Not found'),
        $cgi->end_html;
    }
}


sub resp_hello {
    my $cgi  = shift;   # CGI.pm object
    return if !ref $cgi;
    my $who = $cgi->param('name');   
    print $cgi->header,
        $cgi->start_html("Hello"),
        $cgi->h1("Hello Perl"),
        $cgi->end_html;
}
}


my $pid = MyWebServer->new(XXXX)->background();
print "Use 'kill $pid' to stop server.\n";
```

Thank you.

Comment: How are you calling the perl script through the browser?

Answer (score 0):

Your code is explicitly configured run `resp_hello()` when you access your server's root URL.

```
my %dispatch = (
    '/' => \&resp_hello,
);
```

I don't know exactly what URL structure you are hoping to implement, but if you're trying to differentiate `/` and `/index.html` then you could do something like this:

```
my %dispatch = (
    '/' => \&resp_hello,
    '/index.html' => \&resp_index,
);
```

and then write a `resp_index()` subroutine which opens the `index.html` file and returns the contents to the browser.

You could extend this I suppose and serve any files that exist on the filesystem directly.

But I have to wonder why you're doing this all yourself and not just reaching for a solution that uses [PSGI and Plack](http://plackperl.org/). Where did you get the idea to use HTTP::Server::Simple?

And I'm appalled to see [documentation](https://metacpan.org/pod/HTTP::Server::Simple) that encourages the use of the HTML-generation functions from CGI.pm. We've all known what a terrible idea they are for some considerable time, and [they are now deprecated](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/CGI/lib/CGI.pod#HTML-Generation-functions-should-no-longer-be-used).

Before you spend too long going down this path, I'd urge you to investigate more standard Perl web tools.