# Perl web server: How to route

Tags: apache, perl, url-routing

As seen in my code below, I am using apache to serve my Perl web server. I need Perl to have multple routes for my client as seen in `my %dispatch`. If I figure one out I'm sure the rest will be very similar. If we look at my Subroutine `sub resp_index`, how can I modify this to link to my **index.html** file located in my root: `/var/www/perl` directory?

`/var/www/perl/perlServer.pl`:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

{
    package MyWebServer;

    use HTTP::Server::Simple::CGI;

    use base qw(HTTP::Server::Simple::CGI);

    my %dispatch = (
        '/index.html' => \&resp_index,
        # ...
    );

    sub handle_request {
        my $self = shift;
        my $cgi  = shift;

        my $path = $cgi->path_info();
        my $handler = $dispatch{$path};
        if (ref($handler) eq "CODE") {
            print "HTTP/1.0 200 OK\r\n";
            $handler->($cgi);
        } else {
            print "HTTP/1.0 404 Not found\r\n";
            print $cgi->header,
                $cgi->start_html('Not found'),
                $cgi->h1('Not found'),
                $cgi->end_html;
        }
    }

    sub resp_index {
        my $cgi  = shift;   # CGI.pm object
        return if !ref $cgi;

        my $who = $cgi->param('name');

        print $cgi->header,
            $cgi->start_html("index"),
            $cgi-h1("THIS IS INDEX"),
            $cgi->end_html;
    }
}

my $pid = MyWebServer->new()->background();
print "Use 'kill $pid' to stop server.\n";
```

Comment: Unless this is an exercise, rather than writing your own web server consider a small routing framework like [Dancer](http://perldancer.org/). Also, what's with all the ``\``? Finally, I'm not sure what you're asking. It seems like you're asking how to read a file?

Comment: Tip: `print "HTTP/1.0 200 OK\r\n"; print $cgi->header;` should be `print $cgi->header('text/html', '200 OK');` or, better yet, `print $cgi->header;`

Comment: Tip: `print "HTTP/1.0 404 Not found\r\n"; print $cgi->header;` should be `print $cgi->header('text/html', '404 Not found');`

Comment: Tip: Each `return if !ref $cgi;` should be removed; they are useless.

Comment: Tip: `my $who = $cgi->param('name');` should be removed; the variable is never used.

Comment: Tip: `if (ref($handler) eq "CODE")` can be simplified to `if ($handler)`.

Comment: This is very similar to a [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40276159/making-perl-read-from-index-html-file/40280644#40280644). Is this a class assignment?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think what you're asking is how do you serve a file from your web server? Open it and print it, like any other file.

```
use autodie;

sub resp_index {
    my $cgi  = shift;
    return if !ref $cgi;

    print $cgi->header;

    open my $fh, "<", "/var/www/perl/index.html";
    print <$fh>;
}
```

---

Unless this is an exercise, really, really, REALLY don't write your own web framework. It's going to be slow, buggy, and insecure. Consider a small routing framework like [Dancer](http://perldancer.org/).

For example, mixing documents like `index.html` and executable code like `perlServer.pl` in the same directory invites a security hole. Executable code should be isolated in their own directory so they can be given wholly different permissions and stronger protection.

---

Let's talk about this line...

```
return if !ref $cgi;
```

This line is hiding an error. If your functions are passed the wrong argument, or no argument, it will silently return and you (or the person using this) will have no idea why nothing happened. This should be an error...

```
use Carp;
croak "resp_index() was not given a CGI object" if !ref $cgi;
```

...but really you should use one of the existing function signature modules such as [Method::Signatures](http://metacpan.org/pod/Method::Signatures).

```
use Method::Signatures;

func resp_index(CGI $cgi) {
    ...
}
```